# $\sum\sqrt{\frac{2a}{b+c}}\le\sqrt[3]{9\sum\frac{a}{b}}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers. Prove that:
> $$\sqrt{\frac{2a}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{2b}{c+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{2c}{a+b}}\le\sqrt[3]{9\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)}$$

It is from [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h572052).
Remark: At the end of the linked page arqady (a.k.a Michael Rozenberg) says "It **seems** that the following inequality is also true". So it might be wrong.

Obviously, $\sqrt[3]{9\left(\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}\right)}\ge3$.
So it suffices to show that $\sum\sqrt{\dfrac{2a}{b+c}}\le3$, which is obviously wrong for $(a,b,c)=(10,1,1)$.

Or using Cauchy–Schwarz inequality we have:

$$\sum\sqrt{\dfrac{2a}{b+c}}\le\sqrt{2\left(a+b+c\right)\sum\frac{1}{a+b}}$$

So it suffices to show that $\sqrt{2\left(a+b+c\right)\sum\frac{1}{a+b}}\le\sqrt[3]{9\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)}$, which is wrong for $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$.

Comment: You need a better intermediate bound than this application of C-S.

Comment: You may check $a=b = \frac{1}{100}, c=1$. I think arqady means the following (verified by Mathematica): $$\sqrt[3]{\frac{2a}{b+c}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{2b}{c+a}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{2c}{a+b}}\le\sqrt[3]{9\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)}.$$